# Can't get Apache POI to work in SSJS

Tags: apache-poi, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'm trying to import an excel sheet of any kind (xls/xslx) into my database via an Xpage and the following code returns with an error:

```
importPackage(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel);

var tempFile:java.io.File = fileData.getServerFile();

var wb:WorkBook = WorkbookFactory.create(tempFile);
var sheet:Sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
var rows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
```

*"WorkbookFactory not found"*

I have put the API in buld path: /tradesec(9).nsf/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/poi-3.9-20121203.jar

I have tried this without the importPackage but without luck.  *'org' not found*

Please advice!

/M

**update:**
I have now copied all jars from POI to jvm/lib/ext, added a grant for everything in java.policy, created a java class as a bean.
Still getting exceptions:

```
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:56)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:527)
com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject.construct(JavaAccessObject.java:260)
com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaWrapperObject.construct(JavaWrapperObject.java:1)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTNew.interpret(ASTNew.java:109)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTMember.interpret(ASTMember.java:106)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:88)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTVariableDecl.interpret(ASTVariableDecl.java:82)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(ASTBlock.java:100)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTTry.interpret(ASTTry.java:109)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(ASTBlock.java:100)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTTry.interpret(ASTTry.java:109)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTIf.interpret(ASTIf.java:85)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(ASTBlock.java:100)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTTry.interpret(ASTTry.java:109)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:310)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)
com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:221)
com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptMethodBinding.invoke(JavaScriptMethodBinding.java:111)
com.ibm.xsp.actions.ActionGroup.invoke(ActionGroup.java:135)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.invokePhaseMethodBinding(UIViewRootEx.java:1735)
com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.invokePhaseMethodBinding(FacesControllerImpl.java:444)
com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.access$0(FacesControllerImpl.java:438)
com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl$ViewPhaseListener.beforePhase(FacesControllerImpl.java:527)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:197)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:264)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:248)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:204)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:583)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1281)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:860)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:803)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:572)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1265)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:658)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:481)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:341)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:297)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
```

My knowledge in this section is quite limited I must say.

Currently I'm considering moving away from this and start implementing a plain old text file instead. Too much overhead and dependencies for my tight project schedule to handle, I'm afraid.
If someone out there finds a solution I'm happy to explore it

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that You added poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar to the build path also. The poi-3.9-20121203.jar  jar does not contain WorkbookFactory class.

Comment: Don't forget the [dependencies too](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components)!

Answer (score 1):

There are class loader related problems with dom4j (used by the POI XLSX parser) when loading from the Domino database. Try adding the needed jars to the filesystem in the jvm/lib/ext directory (both Domino and Notes) and opening up the java.security a bit (see http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8JYAT5).

I'm having success with the unrestricted `grant { permission java.security.AllPermission; };`. It would be better to be a bit more restricted, but I have not yet found the time to investigate the issue any further.

You can also try loading the jars by loading the POI 4 XPages OSGi library: http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=POI%204%20XPages

Comment: How can I load the jars from OSGI in SSJS?

Comment: The documentation is linked from the OpenNTF project site: http://my.webgate.biz/poi/documentation.nsf/viewdoc.xsp?docid=installguide

Comment: Read it but I did not find any references on how to reference the OSGI plugon jars…

Comment: OK, now I have tried (everything) but still failing. I made a java class, copied all jars to both client and servers jvm/ext/lib directory, updated policy file to grant everything and I still get exceptions. I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the full path to the WorkbookFactory that is what I have done before when referencing classes within jars.

Comment: Like this perhaps var wb:WorkBook = org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(tempFile);